# Display Excel sheet in web application - Java EE

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

In our web application we are using the snowbound viewer (http://www.snowbound.com/) for viewing documents. It supports all formats but only allows Excel sheet documents to be downloaded and viewed. Direct viewing in the snowbound viewer is not possible.

We have a requirement to display an Excel sheet in a web browser as well. Is there any open source API available to display an Excel sheet in a web browser?

Any solution using HTML5, jQuery, JavaScript or Ext JS is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

My apologies for the late answer. The Snowbound VirtualViewer will view Excel worksheets if you have the Microsoft Office and/or Microsoft Office 2010 option enabled.

Snowbound Software support will help you get past any configuration issues that may prevent this option from working.  http://support.snowbound.com.

If you want to go hard core and do it yourself there is an Open XML SDK for Excel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your excel document as a web page (.mht) and it can be viewed from the browser. If you need interactivity with releases prior to 2007 excel it's easy, but with 2007 excel you need some addon. Check [here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/21435.aspx#imgn_1). There are instructions on how to publish your excel as a web page

Comment: Can we convert the excel document as a web page (.mht) using  program

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  (or)  tags of HTML does it for us... you can have try on these tags... these are used for any kind of docuements like .doc, .xls, .pdf etc...